# Active vs. Attentive vs. Machine Vision

Tags: image-processing

I would like to know a short definition of the three fields

- Active Vision
- Attentive Vision
- Machine Vision

For me it is quite hard to find a specific definition in literature. Sometimes authors group two of them together or use any of them as a synonym.

Comment: hi!, you may get an answer but *definitions* are within the scope of *wiki* pages...

Comment: Yeah for sure. But even Wiki does not have a page or defines a clear line between Active/Machine vision to Attentive Vision.

Comment: @Alex the truth is always in communication between humans: Meaning of words depend on context. You'll really need to look at what you're reading, look at what the "lead" publications of that engineering / scientific scene are, and then try to figure out who they cite when using these terms the first time. Generally, terms are squishy, and these three are very prone to being extra squishy for having been noticed by public relations and marketing departments, so there's a fair chance you'll never find a clear boundary between them. If you're writing something yourself, you can solve that:

Comment: by either explicitly defining them, or referring to a specific publication that defines them.